# How can I pin an application to a workspace in Gnome 3?

Tags: linux, freebsd, gnome3, workspace

I am using a static workspace layout in GNOME 3.18 with the "workspace grid" extension (because I can't stand vertically-stacked workspaces).  It would be great if, when I started an application, the application was always "pinned" to a specific workspace.  For instance, Firefox could always appear on workspace 2, and whenever Firefox opens a new window, those appear on workspace 2 as well.

I can do this on the Mac with the built-in software (with Expose... or whatever they call it now).  I have also achieved the same effect in the past (e.g., using the MATE desktop) with Devil's Pie (https://github.com/GNOME/devilspie), but honestly, it's kind of a hassle to configure.

Is there any built-in mechanism to do this in GNOME 3?  How about extensions?

Bonus points if your solution works on FreeBSD ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/ moves applications to specific workspaces when they create windows.

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. I am looking to be able to move windows based on their name or title as well. I make a lot of application shortcuts from Chrome "apps", webpages.